# Remove space below section in memoir

Tags: spacing, sectioning, memoir, line-spacing

I'm growing tired of the extra space below `\section` and `\subsection` in the memoir class - it's way too big.

How can I remove it - like one use `\vspace{-20pt}$`. This must be done for all `\section` and `\subsection`.

What I have right now:

```
\documentclass[12]{memoir}

%\usepackage[danish]{babel}       
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[bf, small, raggedright, compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}

\section{Section heading} \lipsum[1]

\subsubsection{Subsection} \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've not used memoir but a cursory glance at `texdoc memoir` suggests `\setafterSskip{ skip }`  is what you want with `S` being `sec` or `subsec` and `skip` being whatever length you want.

Comment: Just remember to set it to say `1sp`, since anything non-negative makes it an inline section title. `1sp` is very very small, but not equal to zero.

Comment: Okay, it appears that this is not what I need cause absolutely NOTHING happens...
I think I need to make `\linespread{1}` after each `\section` and `\subsection` and back to 1.5 when the text starts.

Should I do a redefine of the `\section` or can I fix it in another way?

Comment: Your example minus `titlesec` plus `\linespread{1.5}
\setaftersecskip{1sp}` seems fine by me in that there is no extra space below the `\section` it is the same as between lines of text. Remember that `titlesec` overwrites the `memoir` interface.

Comment: Uh - turns out I wrote \subSUBsection and not \subsection *nose poke*.
It looks good now - I think this is what i need.

Comment: @daleif Want to write up a short answer?

Answer (score 6):

Use the built-in stuff from `memoir`. Thus drop `titlesec` and use

```
\OnehalfSpacing
\setaftersecskip{1sp}
```

Rather than setting `\linespread` you should use the `memoir` spacing macros.