# First paragraph indented after section title in margin

Tags: sectioning, indentation, memoir, paragraphs, marginpar

How do you keep the first paragraph from being indented, even when indentation is off, when using section titles in the margin?

I'm pretty new to LaTeX, but I thought I was getting pretty good at it, until I hit this problem I can't seem to resolve. I want block paragraphs, no indent, with section and subsection titles in the outer margin (in the memoir class.) By default, there's not supposed to be an indent in the first paragraph after a section title, anyways, but when I use titles in the margin, there's a 1 em indent for the first paragraph in a section, but *not* in subsections or sub-subsections, even though they use the same settings.

I thought this was related to [this question about almost the same issue in memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15856/first-paragraph-of-section-becomes-indented-after-setting-setbeforesecskip-mem), but the answer didn't work. Adding `\setbeforesecskip`with either a negative or positive value, or tweaking the `\setsecindent` (I started with `[0em]`) simply doesn't fix the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\semiisopage%  a default margin layouts

% fix margin notes

\setmarginnotes{3em}{0.2\textwidth}{2\onelineskip}

%% No numbered sections

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

%% Section Names in margin

 \newcommand{\marginhead}[1]{%
   \marginpar{\bfseries\centering #1}}

%% set section, subsection and subsubsection headers
%% all the same, small bold text

\setsecindent{-1em}
\setbeforesecskip{-2em}
\setaftersecskip{0em}
\setsecheadstyle{\small\marginhead}

\setsubsecindent{0em}
\setaftersubsecskip{0em}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\small\marginhead}

% etc.

%% Paragraph styles
%%
%% no indent, skip line instead

\abnormalparskip{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{First Subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Third Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Remove space below section in memoir](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228298) Ah, not quite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the `\setafterXskip` parameters to a non-zero value (even to a non-detectable `1sp` as in my code below) fixes the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\semiisopage%  a default margin layouts

% fix margin notes

\setmarginnotes{3em}{0.2\textwidth}{2\onelineskip}

%% No numbered sections

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

%% Section Names in margin

 \newcommand{\marginhead}[1]{%
   \marginnote{\bfseries\centering #1}}

%% set section, subsection and subsubsection headers
%% all the same, small bold text

\setsecindent{-1em}
\setbeforesecskip{-2em}
\setaftersecskip{1sp}
\setsecheadstyle{\small\marginhead}

\setsubsecindent{0em}
\setaftersubsecskip{1sp}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\small\marginhead}

% etc.

%% Paragraph styles
%%
%% no indent, skip line instead

\abnormalparskip{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}%
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{First Subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Third Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

A portion of the result:

[image]

I changed `\marginpar` to `\marginnote` from the `marginnote` package.

Comment: But why?  (I got this far too...)

Comment: Marginnote is the only difference to the aforementioned question in my comment above. No dupe i think.

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm asking myself the exact same question. Perhaps this should be a comment and not an answer until the reason has been found?

Comment: @Johannes_B Ahm, then this is a duplicate? On a second thought, I'd like to keep this one open and see if someone can come up with the reason for the problem and why a `1sp` solves it. What do you think?

Comment: Hidden in the comment section: [Remove space below section in memoir](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/336867)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Although the solution is the same, the problem is different. And this question is much clearer, since it has no issues with `titlesec`.

Comment: Also, when I *don't* use `marginnote` the solution doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yeah, marginnote is the real trigger hear, without it there is a little offset. So i think *no* dupe. btw: the last sentence in daleifs answer is great. :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B I've edited daleif's answer now to put it in the correct macro. (So now the sentence is only great in the edit history I'm afraid.)

Comment: I'm marking Gonzalo Medina's answer as accepted, although it does introduce a new problem unless I also use `\marginnote` as he did. The other changes (`\setbeforesecskip`or using a non-zero section indent) can be dropped, though. It's just the `\setaftersecskip{1sp}` that matters.

Comment: I found a fix to [the other problem with title alignment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232654/align-section-titles-in-margins-properly) that happened when I switched to `\marginnote`. Putting `\needspace{4em}` fixed it. Also, I put the `\setbeforesecskip{-2em}` back in, when I was trying to find a fix. It did nothing by itself, but I'm leaving it in, in case it's a combo of all four changes that makes it work.